# Unable to require() from inside an already "required" module

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have this project structure:

```
myApp
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
└── source
    └── scripts
        ├── modules
        │   └── utils.js
        ├── background.js
        └── data.json
```

My `browserify` task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./source/scripts/**/*.js'])
   .pipe($.browserify({
      debug: true,//for source maps
      standalone: pkg['export-symbol']
   }))
   .on('error', function(err){
      console.log(err.message);
      this.emit('end');
    })
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts/'));
});
```

My sample `utils.js`:

```
const data = require('../data.json');

const utils = (function () {
  const output = function () {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return {
    output: output,
  };
}());

module.exports = utils;
```

If I try to build it with the current directory structure, I get this error:

> module "../data.json" not found from "/dev/myApp/source/scripts/fake_4d8cf8a4.js"

I can only build it, if I put `data.json` inside the `modules` directory **AND** inside the `scripts` directory, ie. it only works if I duplicate the file:

```
myApp
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
└── source
    └── scripts
        ├── modules
        │   ├── utils.js
        │   └── data.json
        ├── background.js
        └── data.json
```

Obviously this is not okay... what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Try with  require('../../data.json'); and check the network request for the actual path accessed through the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring from your use of `gulp.src` to pass files to `$.browerify` that you are using a Gulp plugin, probably `gulp-browserify`. It is generally *not recommended* to use a plugin to invoke Browserify from Gulp. The recommended way to do it is to just call Browserify directly. Indeed, Gulp's [blacklist of plugins](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json) states:

```
"gulp-browserify": "use the browserify module directly",
```

I've replicated your directory structure and put some reasonable values for the files for which you did not provide contents (`data.json`, `background.js`) and indeed, I get the same error you get when I try to run the Gulp code you show. However, if I switch to calling Browserify directly, I do not get any error. Here is the code I have:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const browserify = require("browserify");
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  return browserify({
    entries: ["./source/scripts/background.js",
              "./source/scripts/modules/utils.js"],
    debug: true,//for source maps
    standalone: "foo",
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js')) // This sets the name of the output file.
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts/'));
});
```

You use `gulp.src(['./source/scripts/**/*.js'])` in your code, which means that Browserify will take all your `.js` files as entries into the bundle.
So I've put two entries in my code above, which manually replicates the pattern you use with the plugin. **However**, while Browserify does not produce an error with this setup, **I suspect you don't *actually* want to have multiple entries.** Typically, we pass one entry point to Browserify and let it trace the `require` calls to figure what it needs to pull.